# $(this).hasClass('has-success') return false all the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrapvalidator

i am new in jquery and i would like to validate my form in asp.net mvc. for now the validation working for each field but i would like to keep the submit button disabled until
some certain fields was insert in a correctly way. when i finish to insert all the fields the create button is still disabled and i dont know why the

```
$(this).hasClass('has-success')
```

return false all the time

this is the code that i am using:

```
    @model StudentsManagment.Models.student


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>



@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal" id="studentForm">
        <h4>Student</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.First_name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.First_name, new { @class = "form-control", name = "First_name" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.First_name, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Last_name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Last_name, new { @class = "form-control", name = "Last_name" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Last_name, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date_of_birth, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date_of_birth, null, new { @placeholder = "Date: MM-DD-yyyy", @class = "form-control", name = "Date_of_birth" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date_of_birth, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Student_id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Student_id, new { @class = "form-control", name = "Student_id" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Student_id, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.City, new { @class = "form-control", id = "citySearch", name = "City" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, 8, 1, new { @class = "form-control", name = "Description" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
                <div id="messages"></div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-lg btn-success submit-button" disabled="disabled" id="create" />               
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {        
        $('form:first *:input[type!=hidden]:first').focus();
        $('#studentForm').bootstrapValidator({
            container: '#messages',
            feedbackIcons: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                First_name: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The first name is required and cannot be empty'
                        },
                        stringLength: {
                            max: 20,
                            min:2,
                            message: 'The full name must be between 2-20 characters'
                        },
                        regexp: {
                            regexp: /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/i,
                            message: 'The full name can consist of alphabetical english characters and spaces only'
                        }


                    }
                },
                Last_name: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The last name is required and cannot be empty'
                        },
                        stringLength: {
                            max: 20,
                            min: 2,
                            message: 'The full name must be between 2-20 characters'
                        },
                        regexp: {
                            regexp: /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/i,
                            message: 'The full name can consist of alphabetical english characters and spaces only'
                        }
                    }
                },
                Date_of_birth: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The birth date is required and cannot be empty'
                        },
                        date: {
                            message: 'The date is not valid',
                            format: 'MM-DD-YYYY'
                        }
                    }
                },
                Student_id: {
                    validators:{
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The Student id is required and cannot be empty'
                        },
                        regexp: {
                            regexp: /^[0-9\b]+$/,
                            message: 'The student id should conatin only digits'
                        },
                        stringLength: {
                            max: 9,
                            min: 9,
                            message: 'The student id  must be 9 digits'
                        }
                    }
                },
                City:{
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty:{
                            message: 'City cannot be empty'
                        }

                    }
                },
                Description: {
                    validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                            max: 1000,
                            message: 'The description field should be less than 1000 characters '
                        },
                        required: false
                    }
                }

            }
        });      
    });
    $('#studentForm').on('status.field.bv', function (e, data) {
        formIsValid = true;
        console.log("begin:"+formIsValid.toString());
        $('.form-group',$(this)).each(function () {
            formIsValid = formIsValid && $(this).hasClass('has-success');
            console.log("end:" + $(this).parent().hasClass('has-success').toString());
        });

        if (formIsValid) {
            data.bv.disableSubmitButtons(false);
        } else {
            data.bv.disableSubmitButtons(true);
        }

    });

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#citySearch").autocomplete({
            source: function(request,response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/AutoCompleteCity",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.length == 0) {                            
                            alert('No matches!');
                            $("#citySearch").autocomplete("close");
                        }
                        else {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {                                
                                return {
                                    label: item.CityName,
                                    value: item.CityName
                                }

                            }));
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have chekced all the fields... you can specify the particular fields from the each loop.

```
$('#studentForm').on('status.field.bv', function(e, data) {
     formIsValid = true;
     $('.form-group',$(this)).each( function() {
          formIsValid = formIsValid && $(this).hasClass('has-success');
     });

     if(formIsValid) {
          data.bv.disableSubmitButtons(false);
     } else {
          data.bv.disableSubmitButtons(true);
     }
});
```

Comment: first thank you, where should i put this script? should i put it in new <script> scope? and how can i specify the field in the each loop how do you know which filed is the current?

Comment: OK your solution is working great thank you very much

Comment: i have only one problem when i fill all the field except the decription field the create button is enable when i begin to write into the description field the button become disable why is that?

Comment: then make the button 'disabled' in html always until get success from the particular field

Comment: but then if i start from the city field my button is enable with my script code

Comment: in html like <button disabled>... </button>

Comment: i edit my code can you look and see if it is correct? i am working also with asp.net mvc but this is not related to my problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104289/discussion-between-matant-and-banik).